# Is it possible to make multiple function calls in a single transaction?

Tags: transactions

Say I want to make a transaction that calls foo() and the calls bar() afterwards. I could make a contract that calls them both in sequence, but that's kind of a pain. Is there a way to just call both without prompting the user for multiple signatures? And if so will foo() revert if bar() reverts and vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to do this without using a contract.

In general, due to Ethereum's "no features" design principle, anything more complex than a simple transaction will require a smart contract. In this case the contract would be very small, and you can simply deploy it once and reuse it.

Comment: So even the BatchRequest is not atomic? https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#batchrequest

Comment: That simply batches requests from the web3 insurance to the backing node/provider. The requests are still sent to the network separately and are not atomic

Answer (score 3):

You may call all in one transaction by deploying contract looking like this:

```solidity
contract Target {
    function foo () public;
    function bar () public;
}

contract Batch {
  constructor (Target target) public {
    target.foo ();
    target.bar ();
    selfdestruct (msg.sender);
  }
}
```

This will revert `foo()` in case `bar()` will fail.

Though, this will call `foo()` and `bar()` from temporary smart contract address rather than from your real address.

Answer (score 1):

The user signs one transaction. It can involve many contracts and functions, according to design. It will also be atomic - completing or reverting entirely.

There is no way to have the user sign two such transactions or receive the same assurances about two separately signed transactions.

Hope it helps.